# Pagination with console

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pagination

Is it possible to do pagination with console user interface? Let's say I have 30 employee records and I want to show only 10. User press arrow button and they can see the next 10 list. Is it possible?

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE EmployeeReportCursorJawatan CURSOR FOR
        SELECT EMP_ID, NAMA, IC, JAWATAN, GAJI_ASAS, TEL_RUMAH, TEL_BIMBIT, ALAMAT FROM PEKERJA WHERE upper(JAWATAN) LIKE upper(:str);

    EXEC SQL OPEN EmployeeReportCursorJawatan;
    /* loop through the cursor and break the loop when end*/
    EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break;
    while (1)
    {
        /* fetch the data from cursor and display*/
        EXEC SQL FETCH EmployeeReportCursorJawatan INTO :emp_idSearch, :namaSearch, :icSearch, :jawatanSearch, :gajiSearch, :homeSearch, :mobileSearch, :alamatSearch;

    cout<<"\nID\t\t: " << emp_idSearch;
    cout<<"\nName\t\t: " << namaSearch;
    cout<<"\nIC\t\t: " << icSearch;
    cout<<"\nPost\t\t: " << jawatanSearch;
    cout<<"\nSalary\t\t: RM " << gajiSearch;
    cout<<"\nPhone number (H): " << homeSearch;
    cout<<"\nPhone number (M): " << mobileSearch;
    cout<<"\nAddress\t: " << alamatSearch;
    cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------------\n";

        totalCustomer++;
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have a working code but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's actually a lot easier than you think. Here is a piece of code from a program i wrote that does exactly this, the big thing is simply creating a static variable to represent what 'page' the user is on. The rundown

- Use a static variable to represent the page number
- Use an iterator and std::advance to push the iterator to the current page number
- loop through starting at the first element of the page to the last element(in this program i made each page display 10 elements of my lsit

---

```
void ExList::Display()
{
    using std::setw; //save time
    //begin iter starts at page number * 10 since each page has 10 elements
    list<Workout>::iterator PageNum = wrkout.begin(); std::advance(PageNum, AdvanceVar * 10);
    //advance the iter 10 places past PageNum so the loop will run 10 times
    list<Workout>::iterator iterEnd = PageNum; std::advance(iterEnd, 10);
    //formatting for my 'exercise tracker' program
    std::cout << setw(20) << "Page: " << AdvanceVar + 1 << "/" << (((int) wrkout.size()) /  10) + 1
     << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left          //left justified
    << setw(TAB) << "Date"          //print titles
    << setw(TAB) << "Type"
    << setw(TAB) << "Distance"
    << setw(TAB) << "Units"
    << setw(TAB) << "Additional Comments\n"
    << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    //loop through 10 times displaying the proper elements
    for(PageNum; PageNum != iterEnd && PageNum != wrkout.end(); PageNum++)
    {
        std::cout << std::left
        << setw(TAB) << PageNum->Date
        << setw(TAB) << ConvertEnum(PageNum->TYPE)
        << setw(TAB) << PageNum->distance
        << setw(TAB) << PageNum->units
        << setw(TAB) << "Select to review\n";
    }

    std::cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n";


}
```

If you would like to see the entire program for a more in-depth program send me an email

Comment: Do you use any specific library?

Comment: Just the usual C++ librarys that would go along with lists and formatting:  (<list>,<iomanip>,<string>,<algorithm>)

Comment: I need to see the program. Your email address please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The logical solution is to install `more` on the machine, and
have the user pipe the output through this.  But it's not that
difficult to implement.  Basically, you decide how many lines or
entries you will put on one page, then keep track of the index
of the current top of page.  You then output something like:

```
int currentTop = 0;
bool finished = false;
while ( !finished ) {
    clearScreen();
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxOnPage && i + currentTop < entryCount; ++ i ) {
        displayEntry( i + currentTop );
    }
    std::cout << "Continue: ";
    std::string command;
    std::cin >> command;
    switch ( parseCommand( command ) ) {
    case advanceOneLine:
        ++ currentTop;
        break;

    case advanceOnePage:
        currentTop += maxOnPage;
        break;

    case finish:
        finished = true;
        break;

    default:
        //  ???
        break;
    }
}
```